# dynamic vhost configuration based on a substring of the URI

Tags: apache, vhosts

I'm looking to perform a simple redirection to a root directory based on a substring of the URI. For example:

**app1_{substring1}.mydomain.com** will redirect to **C:/wamp/www/substring1**
**app1_{substring2}.mydomain.com** will redirect to **C:/wamp/www/substring2**

ServerAlias allows only wildcard...

Any ideas to implement that ?

Apache version: 2.2.22 (WAMP version)

Comment: Apache version: 2.2.22

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ServerAlias *.mydomain.com
DocumentRoot C:/wamp/www

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !200
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^app1_([a-z0-9A-Z]+)\.mydomain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,L]
```